# white-space nowrap don't work with div below div,and how to get overflow real width

Tags: jquery, html, css

2 Questions:
1. How can I make .mask didn't wrap.
2. After .mask didn't wrap, how can I get .mask real width. It can do with set mask's width, a sure value(like width:200%), but I want mask's width according to the counts of items in it.

```
<div class=" container">
    <div class="mask">
        <div class="smItem">img1</div>
        <div class="smItem">img2</div>
        <div class="smItem">img3</div>
        <div class="smItem">img4</div>
        <div class="smItem">img5</div>
        <div class="smItem">img6</div>
        <div class="smItem">img7</div>
        <div class="smItem">img8</div>
        <div class="smItem">img9</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
        background-color: grey;
        width: 500px;
        height: 105px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    .mask{
        position: relative;
        width: auto;
        white-space: nowrap;

    }
    .smItem{
        float: left;
        width: 80px;
        height: 80px;
        background-color:palevioletred;
        margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
        border: 1px solid;

    }
```

Comment: Please, one question per question.... That is clearer for others when they  search for similar problems

Answer (score 0):

1) To prevent the `.smItem` divs from going to the next line, don't float them but give them `display:inline-block`.

2) If you want to know what the resulting width of the accumulated smItems is in pixels, you'll have to use JavaScript to add up the widths of the items plus the widths of the spaces in between. However, if your goal is to make the `.mask` as wide as its contents, then you're already there. It *is* as wide as its contents!

```css
.container {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 500px;
  height: 105px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.mask {
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.smItem {
  display:inline-block;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  background-color: palevioletred;
  margin: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div class=" container">
  <div class="mask">
    <div class="smItem">img1</div>
    <div class="smItem">img2</div>
    <div class="smItem">img3</div>
    <div class="smItem">img4</div>
    <div class="smItem">img5</div>
    <div class="smItem">img6</div>
    <div class="smItem">img7</div>
    <div class="smItem">img8</div>
    <div class="smItem">img9</div>
  </div>
</div>
```